# How do I remove a random letter from a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to remove a random letter from a string. For example: string: "Hello world"
when i run the program it prints something like "Hlo wrd"

Comment: What do you mean by "random letter"? What program turns `"Hello world"` into `"Hlo wrd"`, and what do you want it to output instead?

Comment: I mean that it removes any letter from the string. By any i mean any.

Comment: Just create a random number between 0 and the length - 1 of your string. Get the character at that number and replace all occurences of it.

Comment: So how did you remove *more* than one letter? (You removed the `e`, two of the three `l`s, and one of the `o`s.)

Comment: idk told just as an example

Comment: but i did like this in my program:
i pasted the statement a few times and changed the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `random.choice()`:

```
import random
string = "Hello world" 
string.replace(random.choice(string), '')
```

Output:

```
'Hello wold'
```

Comment: Optionally do `string.replace(..., n)` to only replace `n` occurrences of the character.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number to pick an index within your string to be removed, and then remove the character at that position.

```py
from random import randrange

text = "hello world"
i = randrange(len(text)) # Get a random index within the text.
strippedText = text[:i] + text[i+1:] # Remove the character at index from our text.
print(strippedText) # Outputs 'helo world'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!!